# Refresh Control in Horizontal UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I want to implement a Refresh Control on my horizontal UICollectionView, but I can't figure out how to implement it. I essentially want to be able to swipe right one the first cell (cells take up the whole screen) and refresh. I've been searching online and found a cocoa pod that is too outdated, and found a way to add one vertically (not what I want), but nothing what I described. Is it even possible to do something like this?

Here's an attempt on the implementation:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset
        let inset = scrollView.contentInset
        let y: CGFloat = offset.x - inset.left
        let reload_distance: CGFloat = -80

        if y < reload_distance{
            shouldReload = true
        }
    }

    override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let _ = scrollView as? UICollectionView {

            currentlyScrolling = false

            if shouldReload {
                reload()
            }
        }
     }
    
    func reload(){
        print("RELOADING")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the third party library mentioned ended up working. Downloading via cocoa pods was giving errors but downloading the code and adding the `.h` files to my bridging header allowed it to work. Here's the repo: https://github.com/hoang-tran/HTPullToRefresh